# No attribute 'set_password' when making a custom User form

Tags: python, django, database, model

so I am trying to make a custom user form for registering and admin thing. The problem is, I try to register someone, and I get the error that there is no attribute 'set_password'. Here is in my views.py:

```
form = RegistrationForm()
if request.method=="POST":
    if request.POST['action']=="register":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Here is the RegistrationForm() in forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="Email", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True, 'type':'email'}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm Email','required':True, 'type':'email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2 =forms.CharField(required=False)

    biography = forms.CharField(label = "Biography",required=False)
    research_place = forms.CharField(label="Research Place",required=False)
    studies = forms.CharField(label="Studies",required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = RegisterUser
        fields = ('email','emailConfirm','password1','biography','research_place','studies')
    def save(self,commit=True):
        RegisterUser = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        RegisterUser.first_name=self.cleaned_data['fname']
        RegisterUser.last_name=self.cleaned_data['lname']
        RegisterUser.biography=self.cleaned_data['biography']
        RegisterUser.research_place="Def"
        RegisterUser.studies="Def"
        print (RegisterUser.studies)

        if commit:
            print("hurr")
            RegisterUser.save()
        return RegisterUser
```

And my models.py:

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    research_place = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    studies = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
```

And finally admin.py:

```
class RegisterInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = RegisterUser
    can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (RegisterInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong, and if there is anything else I should change. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), you need to inherit your `RegisterUser` class from [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) class. You also need to specify some key implementations.

Quoting the docs

> The easiest way to construct a compliant custom User model is to
>   inherit from AbstractBaseUser. AbstractBaseUser provides the core
>   implementation of a User model, including hashed passwords and
>   tokenized password resets.

Other key implementations you need to specify in your custom user model are

- [USERNAME_FIELD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD)
- [REQUIRED_FIELDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS)
- [is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.is_active)
- [get_full_name()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.get_full_name)
- [get_short_name()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.get_short_name)

Comment: When I make it AbstractBaseUser, then it doesnt work to sign up, and my admin page gets an extra "password" field at the bottom (where it should only be biography, profile, research place).